# Indicate a valid procedure call

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I come with a question and hope to get an answer
Well, my question is: **Indicate the correct procedure call**
I wonder about the answers: b or d but I do not know if this is a good "way of thinking"

```
create procedure car2(out average float)
begin
select avg(cena) into average from car;
end //
```

a) call car2 (average);

b) call car2 (@total);

c) call car2 ();

d) Neither answer is correct

Thank you in advance for your answer and maybe explaining why this answer and not another one

Comment: You might find [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html) in the MySQL manual enlightening.

Comment: And what is the answer from that? I have read it.
As I did these call'e in mysql, there were errors with the answers of a and c, while with b there were no but nothing displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer `a) call car2 (average);` may be both correct and incorrect, depends on the place where this statement is written. For example, if it is a statement in another SP which has the variable `average` defined with correct datatype then this statement is correct.

The answer `b) call car2 (@total);` is correct always.

The answer `c) call car2 ();` is incorrect - MySQL does not allow to skip parameters, the error message that the parameters amount does not match the procedure definition will be generated.

So the answer `d) Neither answer is correct` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is (b) **call car2 (@total);**

Option (a) doesn't use an @ symbol to identify a variable, and option (c) doesn't provide a variable at all.

Comment: *Option (a) doesn't use an @ symbol to identify a variable* This can be local variable in some compound statement.